# Getting values and names from fields that have changed in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a form where once a submit bottom is pressed I can see what the Name and Value of the fields that have changed to.

So for example if I have 2 fields, 1. Name and 2. Address. If I change the Name field I'll see 'Name' and the value it has changed to (but not any other fields that have changed)

After trawling SO and the net I came across some code that has helped me. However it serializes the data, and I want to to be formatted differently i.e.

```
<h3>Name: VALUE</h3>
<br>
<h3>Address: VALUE</h3>
```

(note: I only want to see values and names where the input has been changed)

How do I see the name attribute and new inputted values after a submit button has been pressed?

Here is the code I am working with:

HTML

```
<form>
  Name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br/><br/>
  Address:<input type="text" name="Address" /><br/><br/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div class="changed_values "></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input, select, textarea').on('change', function() {
    $(this).addClass('changed');
  });

  $('form').on('submit', function() {
    $('input:not(.changed), textarea:not(.changed)').prop('disabled', true);

    $( ".changed_values" ).prepend( $(this).serialize() );
    return false;
  });
});
```

A JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avveldev/52zgy87v/

Answer (score 1):

Jquery has `.serializeArray()` method to get form elements as an array of names and values.

Use this method to get the form values as an array and use it to display.

Sample output:

> [{"name":"name","value":"John"},{"name":"item","value":"A"}]

Check the below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input, select, textarea').on('change', function() {
    $(this).addClass('changed');
  });
  
  $('form').on('submit', function() {
    $('input:not(.changed), textarea:not(.changed)').prop('disabled', true);
    
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    var displayHtml = data.map(function(val){
     
      return '<h3>'+val.name+': '+val.value+'</h3>';
     
    }).join('<br>');
    
    $("#changedValues").html(displayHtml);
    
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="submit.php" method="get">
  Name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br/><br/>
  Item:<input type="text" name="item" /><br/><br/>
  <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>

<div id="changedValues">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works Great! I'm trying to map the function to a specific button. Like: $('#help :submit').click( function()  but not having much success! How do I map it to a button with an id of help? Thanks!

Comment: Does your form has the id "help"?

Comment: The form is called "verify-form". I have a submit button that's called "help"

Comment: When you click the submit button, the 'submit' event will be fired. Adding click event is not the best practice. You can place the function inside it and then return true to trigger the form submission.

Comment: Ok, its just that I have 4 buttons that are all submit!

Comment: So I just put a .Click event around the function?